How come I can make SSL connections to AWS Postgre RDS, when the ca certificate already expired?
Can I get some helps to solve a puzzle:
I have noticed that the ca certificate on AWS RDS has expired on 8/22/2024. However, I am still able to make fresh connection through psql and dbeaver, and the connections show as SSL true from pg_stat_ssl. the parameter group for the RDS has rds.force_ssl=1 and ssl=1. How come the connections are all SSL enabled with an expired SSL certificate?
select s.*, query from pg_stat_ssl s inner join pg_stat_activity a using(pid) where usename<>'rdsadmin' and application_name='psql';
 pid  | ssl | version |           cipher            | bits | client_dn | client_serial | issuer_dn |                                                                query                                                                 
------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+------+-----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3075 | t   | TLSv1.2 | ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 |  256 |           |               |           | select s.*, query from pg_stat_ssl s inner join pg_stat_activity a using(pid) where usename<>'rdsadmin' and application_name='psql';

(1 row)

I have no experience with this. But if you are using some kind of proxy, load balancer or anything like that, they may be the reason

@AlexanderSantos, thanks. there is no load balancer or rds proxy.

The default configuration will use ssl, but doesn't necessarily verify the CA.  You have to set the mode to "verify-ca" or "verify-full" for that.

See the different SSL modes for PostgreSQL connections here.
You are apparently connecting with an SSL mode setting of allow, prefer, or require. None of which actually check that the SSL certificate of the database server is valid.
You would have to be connecting with verify-ca or perhaps verify-full in order to get an error about the expired RDS SSL certificate.

Thanks very much. However, with the same default setting, some connections had ssl failures with the error in the db log: "could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate expired."
what could be the possible reason for this?

What default settings? These are client-side settings, not server side. Are all the clients using the same SSL mode settings?

So it turns out, none of our client machines specified SSLMODE in connection, which explains why the certificate expired a month ago but didn't cause any disruption, until one machine started to have failures a few days back. And the error message caught in the database log shows "could not accept SSL connection: sslv3 alert certificate expired". We don't know what's on this machine make it unique from others.
